# Display Choice from Select Dropdown Custom Field in Sidebar

Tags: channel-entries, custom-fields, embeds

This is taken from [this](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/228863/) previous thread but I still can't get the answer. Can someone help me?

Basically I am looking to be able to display different sidebar options dependant on what option is picked in a custom field.

Channel = page.

Custom Field = page_sidebar_options - which is a select dropdown with 6 options.

Embed Templates = sidebar_default, sidebar_opt_1, sidebar_opt_2 etc.

Template code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="page" disable="member_data" limit="1" dynamic="no"}
{embed="include/{page_sidebar_options}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The answer given on the EE forums hasn't worked for me. I can get my page to display "sidebar_default", "sidebar_opt_1" etc but not the actual code itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="page" ...}
  {if page_sidebar_options == "default"}{embed="include/sidebar_default"}{/if}
  {if page_sidebar_options == "one"}{embed="include/sidebar_opt_1"}{/if}
  {if page_sidebar_options == "two"}{embed="include/sidebar_opt_2"}{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Hi Jason,thanks for the response. That seems to work but I had to set dynamic to "yes". You're a star! Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Just make sure you understand the dynamic parameter though. Yes means it's going to look in the URL for the entry id or the url title. No means you either want to show all entries or you will specify the entry id or url title specifically.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I can get this to work across 5 different channels without doing the above for each channel and adding an extra custom field to each? Thanks again.

Comment: You'd still have to recreate the field for each channel. But you can reuse the code. Put it in a snippet so you can use it in different templates. Change `page_sidebar_options` to `{channel_short_name}_sidebar_options`. Change the `channel="pages"` to `channel="pages|channel2|channel3|etc"`

Comment: Also, if the answer was helpful, would you mind marking it as correct?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, me again! Did you mean actually use `{channel_short_name}_sidebar_options` as it's written, I've done this but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: The field should be called pages_sidebar_options or channelshortname_sidebar_options, but in the template you'd use {channel_short_name}_sidebar_options.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have done. `{exp:channel:entries channel="page|contact|testimonial|latest_news|news_article" limit="1" dynamic="yes"}{if {channel_short_name}_sidebar_options == "sidebar_default"}{embed="includes/sidebar_default"} 
{/if}` and so on for the rest of the options, but nothing is showing in the sidebar at all now, whereas when it was just 'page' it worked fine.

Comment: Hmm. Apparently you can't do this any longer...
You could try place all of that in an embed, change `{channel_short_name}_sidebar_options` to `{embed:channel}_sidebar_options`, and your embed tag would look like `{embed="includes/sidebar_logic" channel="{channel_short_name}"}`. See http://pastebin.com/A0TZtHcg
(Reasons not to have embeds inside embeds is another discussion...)

Comment: It's cool, I've figured it out. 1 big {if} for each channel, long winded but it works. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Glad you worked something out. My original answer correctly answers your original problem, right? Mark it correct if you don't mind. Thanks!